# How to deploy an Angular/Flask web application?

Tags: angular, flask, deployment

I've been developing an Angular app with python flask as the backend API services for my business. I have looked many different tutorials but I still couldn't figure what I need to do deploy the application. My current project structure is as followed. Backend is the flask project and Frontend is my angular project. It works on my local machine but I would like to deploy the entire application as one project instead of two separate projects like it is right now. What do I need to know in order to configure my deployment?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can server flask application using uwssi and it can be server by nginx server and frontend can be serve directly from nginx.

create as wsgi.py, instance app as application

```
from app import app as application
```

then run the wsgi command in background using supervisor or any other background services. you can go through the below link

[flask application deployment](https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/deploy-flask-app-with-nginx-using-gunicorn-and-supervisor-d7a93aa07c18)